# Redis return value for a string object

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

When I save a string to redis using ServiceStack.Redis:

```
client.Add("key1","abc");
```

While fetching the value, it returns:

```
client.GetValue("key1");
```

it returns

> "\"abc\""

How do I get the complete string?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `client.Add` is the correct method to use? I cannot find it in the documentation. Looks like `client.SetValue` is what you would use.

Comment: Yes, there is a method available called Add. It takes value as object, which is good to create a generic method to pass any value.

Comment: I just tried out the live version. Looks like `client.Add` is adding those quotes, `client.SetValue` is not adding them. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried client.SetValue with a ToString() method for the object and it works better. I can achieve what I want with this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the `client.Add()` method converts the value to a string (even strings) and wraps them in quotes. The `client.SetValue()` method only accepts strings and does not wrap them in quotes.

One option would be to convert the value into a string yourself. Either via the common `ToString()` method, or another method to get the needed string from the object.

If the `Add()` method is necessary however. You could opt to check if the string is wrapped in quotes when you get it via `GetValue()` and if so, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Redis converts string to JSON when saving, that's why it's wrapped in quotes.

So you have to treat this string as JSON object and parse it afterwards manually or using deserialization.